# rpminstall - run shell script inside rpm during install

Tags: linux, rpm

I am working on an RPM which unpackages a tar file into an RPM whenever I run rpmbuild. I have two questions around the process:

1. Is my process of unpackaging the tar file into the RPM correct?
2. When I install the actual rpm onto a server, I'd like it to run a script inside the RPM which I have copied in called `install.sh`. How do I do that?

   ```
   %build
   # let's skip this for now

   %install
   mkdir -p %{buildroot}
   chmod 755 ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/bin/*
   cp -frv ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/bin/* %{buildroot}

   %files
   /*

   %changelog
   # let's skip this for now
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Generally RPM support pre and post installation/uninstall scripts. And they are defined with `%pre`, `%post`, `%preun` and `%postun`. So if you are sure this file (`install.sh`) already exist you can run it on this way:

```
%pre
/path/to/install.sh
```

or

```
%post 
/path/to/install.sh
```

Comment: The `un` means those scripts are run at uninstall time. `%post` is run after install.

Comment: You would want the script content itself to be in the specfile, not in an external file. Your first example wouldn't work because `/path/to/install.sh` isn't yet installed when `%pre` is run.